# Unable to parse JSON from Read The Docs API response

Tags: read-the-docs

I'm sending following REST request to the Read The Docs API:

```
GET /api/v3/projects/<my_project>/redirects/
```

I receive JSON in the response body, but I'm unable to parse the JSON into something useful.

I'm using a Python3 program:

```
import requests
import json
URL = 'https://readthedocs.com/api/v3/projects/<my_project>/redirects/'
TOKEN = "<my_access_token>"
HEADERS = {'Authorization': f'token {TOKEN}'}
response = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS, stream=True)

print(f'Response is {response.json()}')
```

This program returns something that looks like JSON.

If I run it using the following command line:

```
python3 rtd_get_redirects.py | python3 -m json.tool
```

I receive the following error:

```
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

The entire response is large, so I'll just paste this snippet from the beginning:

```
{'count': 521, 'next': 'https://readthedocs.com/api/v3/projects/signalfx-product-docs/redirects/?limit=10&offset=10', 'previous': None, 'results': [{'_links': {'_self': 'https://readthedocs.com/api/v3/projects/signalfx-product-docs/redirects/6612/', 'project': 'https://readthedocs.com/api/v3/projects/signalfx-product-docs/'}, 'created': '2022-07-20T18:08:52.133088Z',
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove the "Response is ..." prefix?

Comment: Good question. I was just using "Response is" for troubleshooting. I ran it again and encountered problems. However, I suspect that the problem might be with json.tool. It might be expecting double instead of single quotes.

Comment: I solved my problem, but the API has a bug.
I had to save the JSON response in a file, and then in that file change all occurrences of single quote (') to double quote ("). I know that I can also do this in Python, but I needed first to be sure it worked.
The bug is obvious: JSON keys need to be in double quotes.

Comment: Try following the example exactly in the RTD API docs: https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/v3.html#redirect-details. Do not use the argument `stream=True`. You do not need to `import json`, as that is a method of requests in this context. Do not use f-strings in the print function.

Comment: Solution: The important part is to read the documentation that Read The Docs provides for the Requests module (import requests). requests.get() returns a Response object (https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response) which contains  properties and functions that you can use to return things of interest.
Response.json() returns "the json-encoded content of a response, if any", although the documentation doesn't describe its type. It's a dictionary.